# How to use Docker for Deploy ReactJS App

Tags: reactjs, docker

I've more questions in my mind.

1. How to use docker for deployment react app?
2. I must to create docker files? or generated by docker?
3. I don't know what should i do with docker.

Can you guys give me simple example using docker for deployment react app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have a server that manage your ReactApp so you need docker in order to have environment to start server that return your frontend application.

Comment: Can i use localhost? I've docker for windows. or Docker just works with server?
can you give me simple example for using docker for deployment?

Comment: docker is just your env lets say "virtual machine" and yes if you start docker on your local machine by default it will be localhost because of network mode host

Comment: Check this out for a comprehensive beginner's guide to what you're looking to do: https://medium.com/@jharvey1012/a-beginners-guide-to-creating-a-containerized-web-application-development-environment-with-docker-e903169004ff

Answer (score 0):

Jackrose,

I created this Medium article to explain how to do exactly what you're looking for. I think running through it would really help you get a good understanding of using Docker to setup your React environment.

https://medium.com/@jharvey1012/a-beginners-guide-to-creating-a-containerized-web-application-development-environment-with-docker-e903169004ff

I'm not trying to just push my own content, I think it would help you a lot. If you have more *specific* questions about using Docker feel free to post and I'm sure we can help you more.